# How to show partial information on private transaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, quorum

I want to achieve the following requirement in quorum blockchain.

```
   1) Participant A sells a red asset to Participant B for 100 dollars. 
   2) Participant B paints the asset blue. 
   3) Participant C cannot see the price for the 
      transaction but can see the asset, owner and color. 
   4) Participant D is added to the network with a new peer.
   5) Participant D can see the asset but is not allowed to paint 
     it because he is not the owner.
```

If we do the private transaction(Node A and Node B) in quroum ,its not possible to see the transaction data for Node C. Because the txn is private for Node B. however i want to achieve the above requirement in quorum blockchain. So i would like to know that if there is any possibilities are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common scenario and theres a really good example called 5 node RTGS that explains in detail one of the ways to address this type of scenario. Heres the link: https://github.com/bacen/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/5nodesRTGS